# I want to converge the keras model with just FC-layer

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a keras model with just FC-layer(Dense). I got train image size `227*227` and `100` class, each class having 1 train image, I would like to overfit and get 100% training accuracy.

Isuue:
I tried to babysit model hyperparameters, but it's not converging to 100% train accuracy. Although, It's just FC-layer even.

Here's my code:

```
X_train, y_train = ...

# Create a Keras Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=input_dim, activation='softmax',
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Callback and training
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training_log_v1.csv')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10000, batch_size=100, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

Here's plot for above code.

[image]

I have ran different hyper-params experiment with 10K to 20K epochs. Loss after some epochs not decreasing and no improvement in train-accuracy.

I tried to play with Different Optimizers(& hyper-params), regularization as well. There's not much hyperparams to play with except optimizer & regularizers here, Right?

If anyone can help me for converging the model that would be great.Thank You!

Comment: Please do not use **HELP NEEDED** in your title or text. It's clear help is needed, or you wouldn't be posting here in the first place. Avoid noise and clutter and useless text in your posts. Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you expect that a *single*-layer NN should be able to overfit a 100-class dataset?

Comment: @desertnaut: I have some experiment to do in designing of weight & bias. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to overfit. Hyper-params, I have used for over-fitting this experiment.

```
Class: 100
Samples_per_class: 1

kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)
activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)

Op: Adam
lr: 0.00001

Epochs set to: 50000
batch_size: 256
```

I got 99% Train-accuracy @around 12K epochs and continued decreasing loss till around 25K epochs.